# Parsing SDP message string in Java

Tags: java, parsing, sdp

Currently I am working on application using SDP messages to establish connection. What I am required to do is create parser for string representation of SDP message and create some kind of structure representing information, also creating such messages from existing structure.

Example from RFC 4566:

```
  v=0
  o=jdoe 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 10.47.16.5
  s=SDP Seminar
  i=A Seminar on the session description protocol
  u=http://www.example.com/seminars/sdp.pdf
  e=j.doe@example.com (Jane Doe)
  c=IN IP4 224.2.17.12/127
  t=2873397496 2873404696
  a=recvonly
  m=audio 49170 RTP/AVP 0
  m=video 51372 RTP/AVP 99
  a=rtpmap:99 h263-1998/90000
```

My question is: **Is there any build in Java tool to parse such message?** I have seen some examples on github to do so, but as I am new to the topic, I am unable to determine which solution will be the best for such task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java has some built-in SIP capabilities named Jain SIP. It is very weak on the media part (no good codec support), however for signaling processing it should fulfill your needs.

Example:

```
import javax.sdp.*;
import javax.sip.*;

ContentTypeHeader contentType = (ContentTypeHeader) msg.getHeader(ContentTypeHeader.NAME);
ContentLengthHeader contentLen = (ContentLengthHeader) msg.getHeader(ContentLengthHeader.NAME);

if ( contentLen.getContentLength() > 0 && contentType.getContentSubType().equals("sdp") ){
    String charset = null;

    if (contentType != null)
        charset = contentType.getParameter("charset");
    if (charset == null)
        charset = "UTF-8"; // RFC 3261

    //Save the SDP content in a String
    byte[] rawContent = msg.getRawContent();
    String sdpContent = new String(rawContent, charset);

    //Use the static method of SdpFactory to parse the content
    SdpFactory sdpFactory = SdpFactory.getInstance();
    SessionDescription sessionDescription = sdpFactory.createSessionDescription(sdpContent);
    Origin origin = sessionDescription.getOrigin();

    System.out.println("A Session ID is " + origin.getSessionId());
} else {
    System.out.println("It is not a SDP content");
}
```

If you don’t like this, then just use an open-source SDP parser such as [jain sip](https://github.com/rkday/jain-sip/tree/master/branches/3263-support/src/javax/sdp) or [jsdp](http://jsdp.sourceforge.net/).

You can also do it by hand yourself following the RFC 4566 as SDP parsing is really simple and can be done with a little string manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am worried about is that I need good media support. As I won`t be using SIP only SDP interests me, and libraries that you have mentionend have few years (they are quite old). Do you think it will be problem ?

Comment: If you are looking for good media support, then you might have a look at [this java sip client](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/Softphones/JVoIP.aspx). Although this is a ready to use SIP client, you can also manipulate the messages (including the SDP) which are sent or received or if you need more access to the SDP then you might ask the developers about it.